# Connect two monitors on macbook pro 2018 by using single docking station

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dock

I am going to buy a Macbook Pro 2018 15". I am just wondering, if it is possible to connect two monitors via one docking station. If there is any docking station, which it supports 2 monitor connections and extending the view (not mirroring). I don't want to use 2 hdmi adapters because I will need to buy the docking station anyway to have usb and ethernet connections.

Comment: Whoever marked  this question as duplicate, has some reading problems... I am not trying to connect 2 Apple cinema displays, I am trying to connect two normal displays... But anyway here is the answer, which I have found.

Buy Caldigit TS3 Dock, buy 1 thunderbolt to "x" adapter to use that adapter as second monitor connector and use display port, which is available on dock, to connect first monitor